# Avoiding cloning references in a Specs system

Tags: game, rust

I'm working on a card game using Amethyst's Specs crate and am fairly new to Rust (therefore I'm learning through the fight with the compiler). My first `System` is to deal the cards to each player. I have:

- a `Card` type that has `Copy` semantics
- a `Cards` component that represents a set of `Card` the players or deck are holding

```
struct Deal {
    deck: Entity,
    players: Vec<Entity>,
}

impl<'a> System<'a> for Deal {
    type SystemData = WriteStorage<'a, Cards>;

    fn run(&mut self, mut cards: Self::SystemData) {
        // code smell - can't use `get_mut`
        let mut deck = cards.get(self.deck).unwrap().clone();
        deck.shuffle();

        for player in self.players.iter().cycle() {
            let player_cards = cards.get_mut(*player).unwrap();
            if let Some(card) = deck.take_top() {
                player_cards.add(card);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        // code smell
        let mut deck = cards.get_mut(self.deck).unwrap();
        deck.clear(); 
    }
}
```

The compiler complains that I can't take a mutable reference to the `deck`'s cards because the `player_cards` is a mutable one (or vice versa).

As noted in the code above, I clone the `Cards` for the `deck`, shuffle that, deal to the mutable players' and then empty the deck.

I would have expected that I could get a mutable reference to the deck up front, shuffle that and remove it.

Is there something simple I am missing?

Aside, I do not know if it is convention to pass entities on the system struct it self or not. Is that wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with ECS or some of the types you used in your code, and to be honest I don't think I quite understand your code as it seems incomplete, but this seems like something that could be fixed by using the [`Rc`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) and [`RefCell`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html) types. Instead of having `cards` as having type `Self::SystemData`, I think you'd want it to be `Rc<RefCell<Self::SystemData>>` instead, which should allow you to create multiple mutable references to it by using the `Rc::clone` function.

Whilst using `Rc` and `RefCell`, you'd still need to make sure that you stick to Rust's borrowing semantics though, as this will then be runtime-checked instead of compile-time checked. [This section of the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch15-05-interior-mutability.html#having-multiple-owners-of-mutable-data-by-combining-rct-and-refcellt) has more information about these types and how they might be used.

I don't have your full code, so I can't check if this is correct, but I think you should end up with something similar to:

```rust
use std::{cell::RefCell, rc::Rc};

struct Deal {
    deck: Entity,
    players: Vec<Entity>,
}

impl<'a> System<'a> for Deal {
    type SystemData = WriteStorage<'a, Cards>;

    fn run(&mut self, mut cards: Rc<RefCell<Self::SystemData>>) {
        let mut deck = Rc::clone(&cards).get(self.deck).unwrap().clone();
        deck.shuffle();

        for player in self.players.iter().cycle() {
            let player_cards = Rc::clone(&cards).get_mut(*player).unwrap();
            if let Some(card) = deck.take_top() {
                player_cards.add(card);
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }

        let mut deck = Rc::clone(&cards).get(self.deck).unwrap().clone();
        deck.clear(); 
    }
}
```

After switching to using `Rc` and `RefCell` in some cases, you might even find that you're able to do without using explicit lifetime annotations, but YMMV.